# how to keep p tag on previous position after leave hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to keep **p** tag on previous position after leave hover that is **top:0px** . I added **top:0px** to **p** in css but not working. Any suggestion? Please help. Thank you.
Below is Snippet for it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hexagon-in1').hover(function(){
    $('.hexagon-in1 p').animate({
       "top":"185px",      
       })
  });
});
```

```css
.hexagon-in1 p{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px ;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red bgone"><p>Beach House</p></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Sagar is it important to do with js?

Comment: I did with css but transition effect that is smoothing effect is not applied even I used transition, that's why I did it with animate Jquery.

Comment: Smoother than this? http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution without "loop" problem

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hexagon-in1')  .mouseover(function() {
  $('.hexagon-in1 p').stop().animate({
       "top":"185px",      
       });
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
   $('.hexagon-in1 p').stop().animate({
       "top":"0px",      
       });
  });
});
```

```css
.hexagon-in1 p{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px ;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red bgone"><p>Beach House</p></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `hover` accept two arguments first callback for hover in and second callback for hover out.
Pass the second argument and do the reverse.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hexagon-in1').hover(
    function(){
      $('.hexagon-in1 p').animate({
          "top":"185px",      
       });
    },
    function(){
      $('.hexagon-in1 p').animate({
          "top":"0px",      
       });
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var position;
    $('.hexagon-in1').hover(function(){
        animate(185);
    }, 
    function(){ 
     animate(0); 
    });
    
    
 function animate(position){
     $('.hexagon-in1 p').animate({
      "top": position + "px",      
     });
    }
});
```

```css
.hexagon-in1 p{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px ;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red bgone"><p>Beach House</p></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

once you trigger your jquery animation CSS is applied and remains.
you need at this point to override this once you do not hover it.

**CSS transition does that really easily**:

```css
.hexagon-in1 p{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px ;
  transition:0.5s;

}
.hexagon-in1:hover p {
  top:185px;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1"><div class="hexagon-in2 red bgone"><p>Beach House</p></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Actually hexagon-in1 is hexagon diagram div and p tag is out of it so, I want to hover  hexagon-in1, so p tag will come from outside to inside. thats why Jquery brother.

Comment: @sagarkodte okay, i understand, your snippet put it inside ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of jQuery man. You can do with css only.

```css
.hexagon-in1 p{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px ;
  transition:.7s all;

}

.hexagon-in1:hover p{
  top: 185px ;
}
```

```html
 <div class="hexagon hexagon-scale"><div class="hexagon-in1">
   <div class="hexagon-in2 red bgone"><p>Beach House</p></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Actually hexagon-in1 is hexagon diagram div and p tag is out of it so, I want to hover  hexagon-in1, so p tag will come from outside to inside. thats why Jquery brother.